# Job-dsl script reading from root directory(/) instead of workspace - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a job dsl script in which i am locating a directory. However it is trying to find that directory from / and not looking inside workspace.
Also i tried to print the current working directory, its displaying / only

```
String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");  
println "current directory is "
println workingDir;
```

**Output :**

```
current directory is 
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it.
I was using "user.dir" which is by default "/" directory(manage jenkins -> system information -> system properties)
I added this and it worked

```
workingDir = "${WORKSPACE}" + "/some_directory"
```